# Can we use a cert to package a .zip file to let only people with cert can open the zip?

Tags: security, zip

Except from using password, can I use a digital cert to assign for encoding the password to prevent people open the zip file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format))

> PKWARE SecureZIP also supports … Digital Certificate-based encryption

Or you could use something like PGP to encrypt a Zip symmetric-encryption password that you want to exchange with another person.

Or you could use PGP to encrypt a zip file (with or without Zip password protection)